# Are these the correct permissions for folders, files and wp-config.php on a WordPress install?

Tags: wordpress

I don't want to lock down everything, since I need the built FTP uploader and caching programs to work correctly on the WordPress sites.

This is what I have found:

Folders - 755

Files - 644

wp-config.php - 444

I'm a little rusty on the SSH commands. Will the following accomplish the files and folders permissions?

`sudo chmod -d 755 /var/www/directory`

`sudo chmod -f 644 /var/www/directory`

They do not look right to me.

Comment: See http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set permissions on directories:

```
find /var/www/directory -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Set permissions on files:

```
find /var/www/directory -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Set the permission for `wp-config.php`:

```
chmod 444 wp-config.php
```

`chmod` does not have a `-d` flag, and the `-f` flag is to suppress error messages.

Also, for WordPress to have automatic updates and all that good stuff, make sure the files are owned or writable by the web server OR PHP (If using PHP-FPM/HHVM).

At the very least, the `/wp-content/uploads` and `/wp-content/upgrade` folder should be writable by the web server/PHP.